# Why doesn't this work in IE?

Tags: html

Trying for this:

```
______________________
|......|.............|
|......|.............|
|......|.............|
|......|.............|
|______|.............|
|......|.............|
|......|.............|
|______|_____________|
```

... but I get this:

```
______________________
|......|.............|
|......|.............|
|......|.............|
|......|.............|
|......|.............|
|......|.............|
|______|.............|
|______|_____________|
```

Here's the code:

```
<div style="width:100%" align="center">
<div style="width: 1100px; padding: 18px; position:absolute; top: 168px; left: 15%; align: left">
<div style="width:100%">

<table style=" width:100%;">
    <tr valign="top">
    <td style="width:170px; height:475px;">
        <div id="vertnav" style="width:170px">NAVBAR</div>
    </td>

    <td width=12px></td>

    <td rowspan="2">
        <div style=" background-color: #f6efdf; padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px; height:590px; overflow-y: scroll;">CONTENT</div>
    </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
    <td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The navigation bar's cell height should be 475, and the content cell's height should be 590px.  With the content height cell spanning two rows, this should make the space under the navigation bar ~125px.  It works in FF, but it is more like 5px in IE.

What am I (or IE) doing wrong?

Comment: It said someone edited my post (probably fixing the little ASCII diagram -- lol), but I went ahead and overwrote it... sorry... but I finally got it right the third time.  :D

Comment: You're using tables for layout, that *is* wrong. Uss CSS and floats instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE has issues with table cell content. It doesn't show empty cells at all. Try putting a `&nbsp;` inside each empty cell.

And a general thought - get rid of the table.

Comment: I attempted using &nbsp; with no success.  As far as getting rid of the table goes, ok... I think that will work, but let's hope I don't screw it up... lol.  Two div's, nav bar with 475 height float:left, content with 590 height and float:right, correct?  Or is that wrong too?  xD

Comment: I would focus on the width, rather than height. Let the height grow as much as it should. Your (and my) mouse has a scroll wheel for that. But the rest seems ok.

Comment: The two div solution works, by the way, and yeah, I'll have to set the widths for sure... I'm using overflow-y: scroll; and a static height (will be modded by javascript) on the content div, though, because it looks better with the background that way.  I'm a superficial bastard sometimes!

Answer (score 1):

It won't validate for a start - the 'width=12px' bit needs quotes around the value.

`<td></td>` pairs without an intervening character (perhaps `&nbsp;`) are likely to give you strange results.

But make sure it validates before worrying about browser differences.

Comment: If you are talking about W3C validation, it passed.  I may have made an error changing the HTML up to make it easier to look at, but the original document passes W3C validation. Thanks for the tip, though.  I'm a little new to web development.  (PS: I attempted putting &nbsp; inside the empty td's, but it only created one line's worth of height.)

Comment: HTML attributes only require quotes around attributes that have white-space in them, unlike XHTML which requires quotes around all attributes.

Comment: @AndyE - thanks for that - it looks so 'wrong' to me, that I'd automatically assumed it must be!